# Opposite of least cost path?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cost-path

I've established how to run a Least Cost Path analysis in ArcGIS, but I'm wondering if you can run an analysis to find the hardest path between two points?

Answer (score 4):

Figured this out. Depending on how you do your LCPA you just have to reverse the new values in the reclassify tool.

Comment: By "reverse" you mean "negate"? A cost of 10 becomes -10, a cost of -3 becomes +3 and so on?

Comment: @Spacedman I don't know if that's what the OP meant, but I definitely don't think you can just multiply costs by -1 to compute the greatest cost path. Many shortest-path algorithms only work with non-negative weights. I think maybe you could get the greatest path by reciprocating the cost, but I'm not 100% sure about that. I'd like to know what was meant by "reverse".

Comment: Hi, to clarify what I meant by reverse was instead of finding the easiest path between two points, it was to find the hardest. Therefore I did a reclass on my slope output from 1-10 to 10-1. So those given a value of 1 were now a 10, 2 was now 9, 3 was now 8 etc. It's worked ok for me and the output was what I expected it would have been.